# Controlling HTML of a WebPart's top-right drop down menu

Tags: asp.net, web-parts, css-sprites

I am reviewing some existing ASP.NET code that used ASP.NET WebParts. The web parts implement `IWebActionable` in order to control the items shown on the web part's top-right drop down menu.

The rendered HTML for each context menu item looks something like this:

```
<DIV>
    <A class="menuItem" onclick="stuff" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <IMG src="something.gif"/>Menu text
    </A>
</DIV>
```

I want to use the [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) technique on the images used for the menu items. However, in order to do this I need to have some control over the rendered HTML, changing it to something more like this:

```
<DIV>
    <A class="menuItem thisItemCssSpriteClass" onclick="stuff" href="javascript:void(0)">
        Menu text
    </A>
</DIV>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - you need to customise the web part "chrome" by creating a class that inherits from `WebPartChrome`. The following article contains an example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webpartchrome.aspx